# IIS MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS

Tags: iis-7, http-status-code-404

Im getting 404 error on my web application, I also try doloto : http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/doloto/ , but reports tell me is an compression issue, I dont think so cause is just one page with some ajaxcontroltoolkit features.

this is the stack :

```
ModuleName IIS Web Core 
Notification 16 
HttpStatus 404 
HttpReason Not Found 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 2147942402 
ConfigExceptionInfo  
Notification MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80070002)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something wrong in your web.config, a path to a request handler is not right.  Verify all of the path information is correct in the `<httpHandlers>` section of your web.config.  Here's an MSDN article that discusses [**registering HTTP handlers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx).